# (flutter) send state to other widget

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, state, stateful

In my Flutter app I want to re-use a custom dialog that received user input. All works fine if I do the `showDialog()` from within the class and have the custom AlertDialog in another class. However, that forces me to re-type the button's onpressed and showdialog sections every single time. I'd prefer to have that also in another reusable class and pass user input to it (and get the button with all functionalities in return). The problem with this is that the user input is not present when the page is loaded, so I need to know the updated state when the button is pressed. And there I get stuck... guessing it should be something with passing the widget's state, but getting lost here.

I created a minimal app to recreate the problem, here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var myTextFieldController = TextEditingController();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Dialog test')),
      body: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        children: [
          TextField(controller: myTextFieldController),
          TestButton().getButton(context, myTextFieldController.text),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestButton {
  Widget getButton(BuildContext context, myText) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      child: const Text('Show Dialog'),
      onPressed: () {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (builder) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text(myText), // is always empty
              );
            });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The AlertDialog's text remains empty , despite text in the TextField. How can I get this to work? Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow these steps:

1. Create a new `String` variable to store the value in the `TextField`.
2. Update the `String` value in the onChanged property of the `TextField` and call setState.
3. Pass the new variable created to `getButton` instead of `myTextFieldController.text`

Code:

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  var myTextFieldController = TextEditingController();
  String textValue =  "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Dialog test')),
      body: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: myTextFieldController,
            onChanged: (v){
              textValue = v;
              setState((){});
            }
          ),
          TestButton().getButton(context, textValue),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Why is the value passed always empty when I use myTextFieldController.text?**

This is because the first value of `myTextFieldController.text` which is "" (empty) is what is being passed to `getButton` and it is not getting updated at `getButton` when the value of the `TextField` changes.

Comment: thanks, this seems indeed to be what I am looking for!  in the test app the textfield does not update but that seems to be a local issue, I will continue with this approach!

Answer (score 0):

#### Call your getbutton mehtod like this.........

`TestButton().getButton(context, myTextFieldController.value.text);`

It works.....Accessing the value attribute of your textfieldcontroller will fix this problem.

Comment: thanks, may work , but for the real-world application I need the other scenario...

Answer (score 0):

This is because initially when you call `TestButton().getButton` a new widget is built with initial value of `myTextFieldController.text` which is empty. Now further down the line when you insert text the value of `myTextFieldController.text` changes, but flutter is still using the widget that was built at first and therefore dialog text does not get updated. The way you can force a rebuild is by using `setState` when `myTextFieldController.text` changes. But it is best to detach the widget and dialog from one another. Right now the widget responsible for showing the dialog is a simple `ElevatedButton`. If it had a fairly complex ui that needed to be used in other places it's better to implement a new widget instead of having a class that returns you a widget in its methods. If you detach the widget from `showDialog` there won't be any need to call `setState` anymore. The following code has two buttons to showcase the difference. The second one just works, for the first one though you'll have to uncomment the `onChanged` of `TextField`:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  var myTextFieldController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Dialog test')),
      body: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: myTextFieldController,

            /// Uncomment the following 3 lines for the first button to work
            // onChanged: (val) {
            //   // setState(() {});
            // },
            ///
          ),
          TestButton().getButton(context, myTextFieldController.text),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => TestButton.showTestDialogue(context, myTextFieldController.text),
            child: const Text('Show Test Dialog'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestButton {
  Widget getButton(BuildContext context, myText) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      child: const Text('Show Dialog'),
      onPressed: () {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (builder) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text(myText), // is always empty
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  static Future showTestDialogue(BuildContext context, myText) {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (builder) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(myText),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, seems like a very elegant solution, but the first button does not update with the setState method, I do have to add explicitly what to update (as in the accepted answer) for it to work